# Javascript 2 elements dependent onclick .toggle

Tags: javascript, troubleshooting

Hi I have two JavaScript elements for logging into and create an account. They both overlap each-other when the div id is clicked and I need them to hide when the other id is clicked and vice versa.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#sign-in').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#login-content').toggle();
    });
});
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#create-account').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#create-content').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want them to alternate the easiest would be to use `show()` and `hide()` rather than `toggle()`, since you don't actually want to toggle the visibility if the login is clicked more than once, you want it to always show the #login and hide the #create. Also note that the `live()` function has been deprecated in favor of `on()`. See this example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#sign-in').on('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#login-content').show();
         jQuery('#create-content').hide();
    });
    jQuery('#create-account').on('click', function(event) { 
         jQuery('#create-content').show();       
         jQuery('#login-content').hide();  
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I want to add some more code so when i click outside the div it hides.